# Computer Strange Ram Usage RamMap

Tags: windows-10, memory

When I keep my computer on for a long time (like 1 or 2 weeks), after examining RamMap, I can see an area where it says Unused Active building up.

Now it's about 400MB, but after 1 week it can go up to 4GB. I can't seem to find the source of this particular section, as it seems very strange that the computer will not release unused RAM but still keep them as active. I never shut down my PC, just hibernate it when I sleep and turn it back on the next morning.

How can I find the source of this RAM leak?

[image: RamMap]

Comment: Have a look at the documentation to understand its output and use your task manager to get an idea of who's using the RAM. Terminate processes and check when it goes away, keep in mind it might just be caching happening for frequent used data.

Answer (score 4):

Check under the "Processes" tab and see if there are any terminated pids still listed.  When I encountered this kind of problem, I had a few hundred thousand records for a single process that was periodically called by a service that wasn't properly disposing the handles.  That lead to both the page table and the unused active memory growing to fill all available memory.  Once I tracked down the service launching the process in question, a restart of the service released the handles and everything freed.

Comment: In my case it was `syntool.exe` and `synergys.exe` (Synergy Keyboard and Mouse sharing client/server). Exactly as you described, hundreds of thousands of entries all consuming 28K.

Comment: Ooof thanks so much! This was my problem as well...it had me stumped 

Comment: I had thousands of wsl.exe entries. Turned out to be Docker for Windows. Killing "Docker Desktop.exe" freed up both page table and unused active RAM.